# Batch file to add today's date, yesterday's date, previous day's date as extension to file name

Tags: date, batch-file, datestamp

The following takes a file, MB5L.txt and compresses it into a zip file with the date as part of the file name:

```
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @(
    Set DayW=%%A
    Set Day=%%B
    Set Month=%%C
    Set Year=%%D
    Set All=%%D%%B%%C
)

"C:\Windows\CWBZIP.EXE" "c:\transfer\ziptest%All%.zip" "C:\transfer\MB5L.txt"
```

Today, it will take MB5L.txt and compress it to ziptest20120204.zip.

I want to take a file named MB5L201202.txt and compress it to MB5L20120202.zip where the "20120202" is a variable, thus allowing an administrator to run a batch file on Monday morning to archive files from the weekend.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want. Do you want the batch file to calculate the date two days ago? There are examples of batch date arithmetic elsewhere on the net, and probably Stack Overflow. If this is what you're after I can probably find you some code.

Answer (score 1):

so you want today date or yesterday to include in the output name?
If yesterday i have done one.. which can share with you!

```
 set yyyy=

set $tok=1-3
for /f "tokens=1 delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do set $d1=%%u
if "%$d1:~0,1%" GTR "9" set $tok=2-4
for /f "tokens=%$tok% delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do (
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=/-,()." %%x in ('echo.^|date') do (
set %%x=%%u
set %%y=%%v
set %%z=%%w
set $d1=
set $tok=))

if "%yyyy%"=="" set yyyy=%yy%
if /I %yyyy% LSS 100 set /A yyyy=2000 + 1%yyyy% - 100

set CurDate=%mm%/%dd%/%yyyy%
set dayCnt=%1

if "%dayCnt%"=="" set dayCnt=1

REM Substract your days here
set /A dd=1%dd% - 100 - %dayCnt%
set /A mm=1%mm% - 100

:CHKDAY
if /I %dd% GTR 0 goto DONE
set /A mm=%mm% - 1
if /I %mm% GTR 0 goto ADJUSTDAY
set /A mm=12
set /A yyyy=%yyyy% - 1

:ADJUSTDAY
if %mm%==1 goto SET31
if %mm%==2 goto LEAPCHK
if %mm%==3 goto SET31
if %mm%==4 goto SET30
if %mm%==5 goto SET31
if %mm%==6 goto SET30
if %mm%==7 goto SET31
if %mm%==8 goto SET31
if %mm%==9 goto SET30
if %mm%==10 goto SET31
if %mm%==11 goto SET30
REM ** Month 12 falls through

:SET31
set /A dd=31 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:SET30
set /A dd=30 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:LEAPCHK
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 4
if not %tt%==0 goto SET28
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 100
if not %tt%==0 goto SET29
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 400
if %tt%==0 goto SET29

:SET28
set /A dd=28 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:SET29
set /A dd=29 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:DONE
if /I %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%
if /I %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%

REM Set IIS and AWS date variables
set IISDT=%yyyy:~2,2%%mm%%dd%
set AWSDT=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%
```

"C:\Windows\CWBZIP.EXE" "c:\transfer\ziptest%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%.zip" "C:\transfer\MB5L.txt"