# Re-naming a file name to include yesterday's date using command prompt

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to rename some log files to yesterday's date when the batch file creates a new file of same name every night.

We can rename the file to today's date using the below cmd

```
ren SampleDTE.TXT SampleDTE-%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.TXT
```

This results in file renamed to // SampleDTE-YYYYDDMM_hhmm.TXT

```
SampleDTE-20132712_1243.TXT
```

I wanted to know how to re-name the file to yesterday's date. Something like

```
 SampleDTE-20132612_1243.TXT
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Batch file to add today's date, yesterday's date, previous day's date as extension to file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143834/batch-file-to-add-todays-date-yesterdays-date-previous-days-date-as-extensi) or [Append +1 to date in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133210/append-1-to-date-in-batch-file) for example...

Comment: Do you run batch everyday? IE, did batch run yesterday so we can store yesterday date?

Comment: @LS_dev I do run the batch every night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way - assuming that you run this regularly, once per day

```dos
FOR /f %%a IN (sampledteyesterday.txt) DO ECHO ren SampleDTE.TXT SampleDTE-%%a_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt
> sampledteyesterday.txt ECHO %date:~10,4%%day%%date:~4,2%
```

Note - `ren` command simply `ECHO`ed. when verified, remove the `ECHO` keyword before the `REN` to activate.

You'll need to set up your `sampledteyesterday.txt` file containing a single line `YYYYDDMM` for yesterday to initialise.

Suggestion: use `YYYYMMDD` which sorts easier or more logically...

Comment: yes I run this regularly once a day. I tried using your command but it always returns '%%a was unexpected at this time.' . I have created a **sampledteyesterday.txt** containing YYYYMMDD . What's that I am missing?

Comment: It always returns...what?

Comment: You seem to be running the command from the prompt. When running a command from the prompt, you need to reduce all usages of the metavariable `%%a` (in this case) to `%a`. It's so much easier to run this as a batch file though - double-plus immune to tyops. Take the lines, as they are, pop a line `@echo off` as the first line and `setlocal` as a second and save as a file named (eg) `rensampledte.bat`. From the prompt, `rensampledte` will then execute the batch file. With a little work, you can then schedule it to run using task scheduler, so it would run automatically once per day.

Comment: Yup i was trying it in cmd line to test. Now I tried in cmd & .bat this works real good. Thanks a lot. This batch kicks depending on the success of other. So no need to schedule time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a variable and do the math:

```
set /a day=%date:~7,2% - 1
ren SampleDTE.TXT SampleDTE-%date:~10,4%%day%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.TXT
```

Comment: Ooh - be careful! There's a couple of gotchas here. First is that if the day is <10, the leading '0' will be suppressed - and the `0`th of a month seems a little odd. Second is that a leading `0` as part of a `SET/A` statement  means that the element is in OCTAL, so on day=08 or day=09, the `set` will fail because `08` and `09` are not valid octal numbers. A cure is `set /a day=1%date:~7,2% - 1` and then use `%day:~-2%` in the `ren` string. Trying to get the last day of last month to play nice is not straight-forward...

Comment: Ahhhh... @Magoo Thanks I will make these changes. Still waiting to try out the other one you answered earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This will get yesterdays date, using VBS in a batch file.

It's reliable in all locales, whereas the %date% variable can be different on different computers, and different users.

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "date-yesterday=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"

echo Yesterday was "%date-yesterday%"
pause
```

Comment: Cool! I have no idea about VB scripting but this serves the purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid date arithmetics, you can store yesterday date in, eg, file.

`yesterday.txt` (contains today and yesterday):

```
20131227 20131226
```

Batch file:

```
REM Get today (to check if yesterday.txt is valid):
SET today=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~4,2%
REM Read file:
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2" %%d IN (yesterday.txt) DO (
    SET stored_today=%%d
    SET yesterday=%%e
)
REM If stored_today not equal to today, assume yesterday is stored_today and update file:
IF NOT "%stored_today%" == "%today%" (
    SET yesterday=%stored_today%
    >yesterday.txt ECHO %stored_today% %today%
)
REM Test if yesterday is set, exit otherwise.
IF "%yesterday%"=="" ECHO Yesterday unknown! Try again tomorrow.&GOTO:EOF
```

To make it work correctly first time, `yesterday.txt` must be manually filled.